# Restarting a Sencha Touch App

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, sencha-touch, extjs

I'm currently working with a Sencha Touch localized app, and all of the string values such as titles, labels and forms are generated on launch, meaning that if I want to switch the language I need to reload the whole app.

Is there a way I can restart/reload the whole application or views without refreshing the browser?

Comment: Try Caching:
http://www.sencha.com/learn/taking-sencha-touch-apps-offline/

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Nope, refreshing the window was the only solution, as the `launch()` method mentioned below doesn't rebuild the whole app. 
Since our requirements changed we didn't need this anymore, but a fast workaround that'd work would be saving to localStorage the selected language value and reloading the window , and reading it on start (although I remember there was a problem with that as well)

Answer (score 0):

You can always fire a `launch event` in the `Ext.Application` class, this will invoke all the app initialization code without refreshing the browser

Answer (score 0):

Try using the native JavaScript code for reloading the session
i-e

```
location.reload();
```